# Column name or number of supplied values doesn't match table definition sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I am trying to insert values in  table by using the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD NrLeg_sot varchar(5)

INSERT INTO student 
VALUES ('117', 'Popescu', 'F', 'Florentina', 'f', CONVERT (smalldatetime, '15/04/1978', 103), 'C', '223', '102')
```

And I have this table:

```
DROP TABLE student;

CREATE TABLE student 
(
    NrLeg int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Initiala varchar(5),
    Prenume varchar(20),
    Grupa int,
    Nota int,
    CodDisciplina int ,
    gen varchar(5),
    DataS  datetime
);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Why?

Comment: You need a `GO` between your `alter table` and your `insert` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @DaleK That error is not associated and caused/related to the `GO`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(
'117',     -- maps to NrLeg which has data type int
'Popescu', -- maps to Name
'F',       -- maps to Initiala
'Florentina', -- maps to Prenume
'f',       -- maps to Grupa, which is of data type int
CONVERT (smalldatetime,'15/04/1978',103), -- maps to Nota, also an int
'C',       -- maps to CodDiscipline, an int
'223',     -- maps to gen
'102'      -- maps to DataS, a datetime
)
```

IOW there's not much that would work in your insert statement.
But if you'd add the list of column names (and adjust the data types), the database engine knows how to map the specified values to the columns:

```
INSERT INTO student (NrLeg, Name, Initiala, Prenume, gen, DataS, Grupa, Nota,
                     CodDiscipline)
VALUES(
117,       -- maps to NrLeg which has data type int
'Popescu', -- maps to Name
'F',       -- maps to Initiala
'Florentina', -- maps to Prenume
'f',       -- maps to gen
CONVERT (smalldatetime,'15/04/1978',103), -- maps to DataS
'C',       -- maps to Grupa, an int, this is still a problem
223,       -- maps to Nota
102        -- maps to CodDiscipline
)
```

You'd still have a problem with the value 'C' though.

Answer (score 0):

You can match with the following query. You should pass the integer column value without a single quote.

Also, the sequence and number of column count are easily verifiable when you write your query in the following formatted way.

```
create table student (
    NrLeg int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Initiala varchar(5),
    Prenume varchar(20),
    Grupa int,
    Nota int,
    CodDisciplina int ,
    gen varchar(5),
    DataS  datetime
); 

ALTER TABLE student ADD NrLeg_sot varchar(5)

INSERT INTO student 
VALUES(117 --NrLeg
,'Popescu' --Name
,'F' --Initiala 
,'Florentina' --Prenume
, 0 --Grupa
, 0 --Nota
, 0 --CodDisciplina
,'C' --gen
,CONVERT (smalldatetime,'15/04/1978',103) --DataS
,'102' --NrLeg_sot
)

Select * from student
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=813874b6581bd1d1aed94595d311038c) demo.

*It is a good practice to pass the column name in bracket while inserting in the table as shown below.*

```
INSERT INTO student (<column1 name>, <column2 name>, <column3 name>, ...)
Values(<column1 value>, <column2 value>, <column3 value>, ...)
```

Comment: FYI: You can pass quoted integers in SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK That idea has been revised and edited as per your second suggestion. In OP case there were other issues also and that was just a suggestion not to use a single quote for passing the integer values.